# Datastore disabled after migration to HR

Tags: google-app-engine

I've migrated an app to H/R datastore. Now I'm getting:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CapabilityDisabledException: The API call datastore_v3.Delete() is temporarily unavailable: Datastore writes have been disabled by an application administrator. Writes can be re-enabled in the admin console.
```

on the target app.
I tried to disable/enable writes but no luck.
App-id is: greencard-sg

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via app engine dashboard, shutdown all the existing instances and then remove them, wait for a few minutes and do a fresh deployment, make sure your deployment configuration is HRD. it should work.

-Hope it helps.